# Identify the nature of field error in django forms

Tags: django-templates, django-forms

The 2 types of validation error a form field in django can have are 'required' and 'invalid'. Is there any way to find out which of these two errors has happened, from the template? Something like

```
{% if form.username.errors %}
{% for error in form.username.errors %}
{% if error.required %}
Please enter the username
{% else %}
{{ error }}
{% endif %}
```

I just want to override the error message for the 'required' error, i.e., I want to display my own error message if that error happens. I am using `django.contrib.auth.views` which uses `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm` which I don't want to try customizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should just override the Authentication form. The view accepts an argument that allows for you to override form easily.

I think something like this should work:

<strike>All you need to do is override the clean_username method like so:</strike>
edit:

overriding the clean_username method fails to change the validation error message because of the following from the [**`form and field validation docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/):

> - The clean() method on a Field
>     subclass. This is responsible for
>     running to_python, validate and
>     run_validators in the correct order
>     and propagating their errors. If, at
>     any time, any of the methods raise
>     ValidationError, the validation stops
>     and that error is raised. This method
>     returns the clean data, which is then
>     inserted into the cleaned_data
>     dictionary of the form.
> - The `clean_<fieldname>()` method in a
>     form subclass – where  is
>     replaced with the name of the form
>     field attribute. This method does any
>     cleaning that is specific to that
>     particular attribute, unrelated to the
>     type of field that it is. This method
>     is not passed any parameters. You will
>     need to look up the value of the field
>     in self.cleaned_data and remember that
>     it will be a Python object at this
>     point, not the original string
>     submitted in the form (it will be in
>     cleaned_data because the general field
>     clean() method, above, has already
>     cleaned the data once).

The Field subclass is validated first and returns the cleaned data that is used for the `clean_<field_name>()` method. If an error occurs there the validation of that field stops.

This means that to override the message you need to either override the Field validation or make the field not require a value so no validation error is raised at that step and raise a required method in the `clean_<fieldname>()` method

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
>>> class MyAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         super(MyAuthForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
...         self.fields['username'].error_messages['required']='Custom Required Msg'
... 
>>> form = MyAuthForm(data={'password':'asdf'})
>>> form.is_valid()
False
>>> form.errors
{'username': [u'Custom Required Msg']}
>>>
```

urls.py

```
from someapp.forms import MyAuthForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'someapp/login.html', 'authentication_form':MyAuthForm, }),
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, seems a sensible way of doing this. :-)

Comment: I tried this, but I am still getting only the 'This field is required error' that is the default. I just wrote my own clean_username and clean_password using the exactly same login as the above example but doesn't seem to work. Any clues?

Comment: did you pass the authentication form to the view in the urlconf?

Comment: Yes, I set the `authentication_form` parameter to my custom form. But still default validation seems to work. I am not sure about the order in which the validation functions are called and what will happen if one exception is raised.

Comment: Okay, I think i figured out why you aren't able to change the validation error with the above method. Editing the answer.

Comment: @DTing, thanks. I will try the new approach and get back in case of queries/doubts.

Comment: @DTing,I was able to customize the 'required' error message using the way you have suggested. How do I change the error message shown when the authentication has failed? The default error message is raised in the validation of the fields and not from a dictionary of error messages. The message is `Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive.`

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are searching for this type of handle in html template

```
{% for x in form.errors %}
    {%if "__all__" in x %}
        Wrong username and password
    {%else%}
        {%if "username" in x %}
            Requires username
            <br>
        {%endif%}
        {%if "password" in x %}
            Requires Password
            <br>
        {%endif%}
    {%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

Messages will be printed like this on your login page

Requires username 
Requires Password

Wrong username and password